# AJAX не вызывает представление частично

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

**ReportController.cs**

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Report()
        {
            var model = await GetRMschools(User.Identity.Name);
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<List<RMschool>> GetRMschools(string _schoolID)        
        {
            Account account = new Account("chr_coko.pto@mail.ru", "***");
            var api = new MailRuCloud();
            api.Account = account;            
            var items = await api.GetItems($@"/Reports/{_schoolID}");            

            school school_current = schoolRepository.GetT(_schoolID);
            List<RMschool> model = new List<RMschool>();            
            foreach (var file_name in items.Files) //e.g. file_name = "0001_201636.zip"
            {
                int report_code = Convert.ToInt32(file_name.Name.Substring(5, 6)); //e.g. report_code = 201636
                var ob = monit95Context.ReportMetas.Find(report_code);
                model.Add(new RMschool
                {
                    code = ob.code,
                    name = ob.name,
                    ProjectName = ob.ProjectName,
                    year = ob.year,
                    WWWref = $@"{school_current.ReportLink}/{file_name.Name}"
                });
            }
            return model;
        }
```

**Report.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<Monit95App.Models.RMschool>

<h2>Отчеты</h2>

@{ Html.RenderPartial("_GetRMschools", Model);}
```

**_GetRMschools.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<Monit95App.Models.RMschool>

    <body>
        <table class="table">
            <thead class="thead-inverse">
                <tr>
                    <th>Проект</th>
                    <th>Отчет</th>
                    <th>Учебный год</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            @foreach (var reportMeta in Model.OrderByDescending(x => x.code))
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@reportMeta.ProjectName</td>
                    <td><a href="@reportMeta.WWWref">@reportMeta.name</a></td>
                    <td>@reportMeta.year</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </body>
```

А теперь вопрос начинается отсюда):

**Schools.cshtml**

```
    <body>
        <h4>Выбор</h4>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Район:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AreaNames, Model.AreaNames, "--Выбрать--", new { @id = "ddlArea" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Образовательная организация:</label>
                </td>
                <td id="School">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SchoolNames, new List<SelectListItem>(), "--Выбрать--", new { @id = "ddlSchool" });
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <hr />

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li id="li_1"><a href="#">Реквизиты</a></li>        
            <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Отчеты", "Report", "Report",  new  {_schoolID = User.Identity.Name },  
                                                                new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "tabContent" })
            </li>
        </ul>
   <div id="tabContent">

    </div>

...
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Мне необходимо чтобы результат ссылки `AJAX` помещался в блок `<div id=tabContext>` с сохранением выше стоящей информации. А вместо этого он вызывает чисто результат представления Report.cshtml:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ЧТО Я ДЕЛАЮ НЕ ТАК?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему ненавязчивый аякс не работает :с, попробуйте это:
1) Проверьте, что установлен nuget пакет

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax
```

2) Что скрипт добавлен на страницу
3) Если первые два пункта сделаны и все равно не работает, могу только порекомендовать обычный jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ссылка",
    type: "GET",
    data: "@User.Identity.Name",//если в Razor
    success: function(data){
        $("#tabContent").html(data)
    }
    error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
        //error Handle
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

В представлении надо подключить библиотеки

```
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, форматируйте код. Выделяете и нажимаете Ctrl + K